# Can you get a virus from downloading a .avi file?

Tags: virus, bittorrent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can avi files contain a virus?](https://superuser.com/questions/445366/can-avi-files-contain-a-virus)

Can you get a virus from downloading a .avi file? (say from torrent)